# "Inconsistencies in the existing project dependencies found" error when using Navigation from Android Jetpack

Tags: android-studio, gradle, dependencies, build.gradle, android-jetpack-navigation

This problem started right after I updated my gradle version and gradle plugin, then I just updated android studio to Artic Fox 2020.3.1 and now I have gradle version 7.0.2 and gradle plugin 7.0.0.

I'm fairly new using android jetpack, I've been trying to use navgraphs so when I open navigation/my_navgraph.xml Android Studio tells me to add navigation dependencies but It has this "Inconsistencies in the existing project dependencies found" message that unables me to compile properly:

[Message after opening my_navgraph.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RO0ij.png)

This is my app level build.gradle:

```
 plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app.prueba"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

And this is the project level build.graddle:

```
   // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.20"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Any ideas?, I think just messed up my gradle configuration or something, I will appreciate your help

Comment: hey how did you fixed it, got the same problem